# Is it possible to use python-ldap get user's password?

Tags: python, ldap

As title said, I want to use python_ldap to get user's password.

Here is python-ldap reference,
http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/index.html

I didn't find any function to get user's password.

Is there anybody do the same thing like me?

And is it possible to get user's password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you query an LDAP directory for a given organizational unit, common name, etc. and find things like passwords as attributes.  It means you have to know something about the LDAP schema.  There's nothing in your question to indicate that you do.

Comment: Right. What *duffymo* said. A password is just another attribute in an LDAP schema, albeit one with some special properties. To get a user's password, you have to query the LDAP server (which typically means that you have to authenticate to the LDAP server first), find the user, and retrieve the password attribute.

Comment: Thank you duffymo, Brian, now I know what I'm gonna do.

Comment: Actually, I ask this question because I thought here might be LDAP can't access to user's password. thanks again.

Comment: If *duffymo's* answer was helpful to you, you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

No system that is designed to be secure will allow access to clear-text passwords. In fact, the system won't even know the clear-text password.

You might want to re-think exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I can get password encrypted, that's not I want. I'll try to change my way.

Answer (score 2):

No, an ldap server will not send out passwords, plain or encrypted.
You can only write them if you provide the correct credentials.